# Should I delete my answers that duplicate other users' answers?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you delete your own answer when it’s a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate)

When answering a question on Stack Overflow, I'll often find that in the time it took me to write out my response someone else has responded with a better version of what I was going to say. Is it appropriate for me to delete my answer, or should I just leave it there and hope someone wrings something new out of it?

Comment: Aha; perhaps I should delete this question, then? :)

Comment: no don't please, it will be closed shortly, then it will help redirect people whose searches lead them to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't add anything new, or isn't written much better, then just delete it (or change  it to be so).